# How to get channelid in pubnub subscribe/or publish function?

Tags: node.js, pubnub

This my subscribe code i want to get the channelid so i used **this.channel** in the code but i got undefined. Is there any way that i can get channelid

```
pubnub.subscribe({
    channel: changing dynamically,
    presence: function (m) {
        console.log(m)
    },
    message: function (m) {
        console.log(m);
        console.log("Channel ==" + this.channel)
    },
    error: function (error) {
        // Handle error here
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
})
```

result:
Channel==undefined

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the fine manual](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/nodejs-javascript/api-reference#subscribe_example_1), this should work:

```
pubnub.subscribe({
    channel: changing dynamically,
    presence: function (m) {
        console.log(m)
    },
    message: function (m, env, channel) {
        console.log(m);
        console.log("Channel ==" + channel)
    },
    error: function (error) {
        // Handle error here
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
})
```

In other words, the channel is passed as argument to the `message` callback.

The most likely reason for `this.channel` being undefined is that the `message` callback isn't called in the context of the object that is passed to `pubnub.subscribe()`.